# Conversion of hex to Float in SciLab

Tags: floating-point, hex, type-conversion, scilab

I'm trying to read a float number in a hex representation f.ex

```
43079A11
```

which should give me 135.601822, (similar to what this site does http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/32bit.html)
using SciLab.
When I try with the hex2dec function, I instead get

```
hex2dec('43079A11')
ans  =
1.125D+09
```

I'm not well versed in IEEE and floating point systems in general so bear with me. What can I do to generate the right result?

Comment: I took the liberty of moving your answer to a proper place: the answer box. Yes, all Scilab variables are double precision.

Answer (score 0):

[Written by the question author.] I found a solution using the [FloatingPoint package](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/floatingpoint/):

```
flps = flps_systemnew("IEEEsingle")
flpn = flps_numbernew ( "hex" , flps , '43079A11')
res = flps_numbereval(flpn)
```

Without a package, it seems like SciLab cannot do single-point precision at all.